# C: Reading more bytes than format string wIth format string injection

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting, exploit

In the paper [Exploiting Format String Vulnerabilities](https://crypto.stanford.edu/cs155/papers/formatstring-1.2.pdf) the authors give the following code sample where `input` is some unfiltered user input.

```
char outbuf[512];
char buffer[512];
sprintf (buffer, "ERR Wrong command: %400s", input);
sprintf (outbuf, buffer);
```

They then explain that by using a special format string as input they can bypass the `%400s` limitation:

```
"%497d\x3c\xd3\xff\xbf<nops><shellcode>"
```

This creates a string which is 479 characters long. However, I can't find an explaination for how `%479d` bypasses the `%400s` limitation. How does this input enable sprintf to write a string which is longer than 400 characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second `sprintf()` overflows `outbuf` because it uses a format string generated by the first `sprintf()`, and placing "%497d" in that string makes it print a 497-char wide integer field (padded with spaces to get the full width).  This along with the rest of that string, would exceed the 512-char `outbuf` buffer size.  It would also make it try to read an integer argument that's not actually passed to the function (2nd `sprintf()`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if `input` contains `%` markers, then `buffer` will contain those `%` markers (after the first `sprintf()`), and then using the second `sprintf()`, the 'format string' is `buffer` and the `%` markers in it will be interpreted, even though there are no arguments to interpolate into `outbuf`.  To avoid the problem:

```
snprintf(outbuf, sizeof(outbuf), "%s", buffer);
```

or

```
strcpy(outbuf, buffer);
```

In this context, `snprintf()` is overkill, but it is stripping the mechanism down to basics.